# Oculus Rift in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, sharpdx, oculus

I'm trying to use Oculus Rift DK2 with .Net in order to display live video stream

I'm able to sample the video (rtmp) using Emgu or ffmpeg, and then display it with SharpDX on screen.

But I'm struggling to make oculus rift to display it. Now I'm using SharpOVR wrapper.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

This is some of the code:

program.cs:

```
 using (var program = new RiftGame())
            program.Run();
```

RiftGame.cs

```
using SharpOVR;
using SharpDX;
...

Queue<System.Drawing.Bitmap> _images;

void _tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_capture == null)
    {
        _capture = new Capture(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CaptureType.Any);
    }

    System.Drawing.Bitmap image = _capture.QueryFrame().Bitmap;
    _images.Enqueue(image);
}     


protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    _graphicsDeviceManager.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 480;
    _graphicsDeviceManager.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 800;

    var image = _images.Dequeue();

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {

        image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        ms.Position = 0;
        tex = Texture2D.Load(GraphicsDevice, ms);                        
    }


    Vector2 planePosition = new Vector2(
       (this.GraphicsDevice.BackBuffer.Width / 2.0f) - (tex.Width / 2.0f),
       (this.GraphicsDevice.BackBuffer.Height / 2.0f) - (tex.Height / 2.0f));

    _spriteBatch.Begin();

    _spriteBatch.Draw(tex, planePosition, Color.White);

    _spriteBatch.End();

    _spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, GraphicsDevice.BlendStates.NonPremultiplied);
    _spriteBatch.End();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```